# Makefile Java - Compilar 2 archivos a la vez

Tags: java, makefile, make

Me gustaría saber como crear un makefile de forma que compile 2 archivos .java a la vez, es decir, el equivalente a la siguiente línea de código:

```
javac -classpath ~ruta/al/servlet/servlet-api.jar ARCHIVOA.java ARCHIVOB.java
```

He llegado hasta este punto:

```
JFLAG   =-classpath
JFLAG2  =-d
JC  =javac
RUTA    =~/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/lib/servlet-api.jar
RUTASALIDA  =~/carpeta_destino
DIRJAVAS    =~/carpeta_javas
.SUFFIXES:  .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAG2) $(RUTASALIDA) $(JFLAG) $(RUTA) $*.java

CLASSES = \
     ARCHIVOA.java \
     ARCHIVOB.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

El problema es que compila el ARCHIVOA.java pero no el ARCHIVOB.java, y para que se compile correctamente el programa se necesita la compilación conjunta como se produce cuando se invoca la línea de código mencionada arriba

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Hay algún motivo en particular por el que quieras compilar tu proyecto con un Makefile (que tradicionalmente se ha usado para proyectos C/C++) en lugar de con herramientas específicas de Java tales como Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc.?

Comment: Hola muy buenas, pues simplemente porque así me lo especifican en el proyecto que estoy realizando. No es una preferencia personal ni nada por el estilo